# Wrap item with vertical margin

Tags: spacing, margins, white-space, vspace

I have some cases where I will have an item in between two paragraphs. For
example:

```
Alfa bravo:

\includegraphics{a.jpg}

charlie delta:

\begin{verbatim}
echo foxtrot
\end{verbatim}

golf hotel
```

the image gets no vertical space at all, the the code block does get some space,
but I might want more. I can add some of these:

```
\bigbreak
\vspace{1cm}
```

but is a better option available? Something like one of these:

```
\includegraphics[margin=1cm]{a.jpg}

\begin[margin=1cm]{verbatim}
echo foxtrot
\end{verbatim}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I used the `tcolorbox` package. The `beforeafter skip` option
sets the top and bottom margin. The `listing only` option to the `tcblisting`
element gives a similar result to `verbatim`.

This does add a background and border to these elements, but I actually like
that. If someone dislikes that, I think it can be disabled in the settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{beforeafter skip=8mm}
\tcbset{listing only}
\begin{document}

Alfa

\begin{tcolorbox}
\includegraphics{a.jpg}
\end{tcolorbox}

Bravo

\begin{tcblisting}{}
Charlie
Delta
\end{tcblisting}

Echo

\end{document}
```

http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf

Comment: I usually use much simpler environments: `{center}` or `{flushleft}` (depending on desired positioning) to give the standard separation for the document.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau what do those have to do with vertial margins?

Comment: They have vertical separation at top and bottom, `\topsep + \parsep` (yes at the bottom too).